# iOS StreamingKit Framework Encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, streaming

I am considering using the following framework to streaming audio in an iOS app, on the GitHub page it mentions it allows encryption/decryption but i cannot find any documentation on it!

Has anyone been able to achieve this and if so, how?

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

Comment: Curious, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The only code that I can see that deals with encryption is the ability to stream using a https URL and the ability to decode a variety of encoded audio types.  What additional capabilities were you looking for?